# cargo build stuck when add rand = "0.3.0" in Cargo.toml file

Tags: ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo

I am trying the Rust guessing game

My `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "guessing_game"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["grv07"]
[dependencies]
rand = "0.3.0"
```

Now when I run `cargo build`, it is stuck on:

```
Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `cargo build --verbose`?

Comment: That step clones the repository `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`. What happens when you try to do that yourself?

Comment: This is probably a silly question but are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Also, stuck on for *how long?*  I've had cases where updating the registry took over half an hour, with no visible progress.  It *was* working... just unfathomably slowly.

Comment: @ljedrz it just show me >> Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index` and wait.

Comment: @GrvTyagi I was hoping for something more informative; what is your Internet connection speed? How long have you let this command run? Does it break at any point in time?

Comment: yah my internet was too slow last night, now it is working fine.
sorry for time.

Comment: Consider removing your question.